# POSTed arrays keep their values

Tags: php, wordpress, dashboard, advanced-custom-fields

Today I noticed one of my Wordpress installations is behaving in a very strange way: whenever I update a post from the Dashboard, some of its extra inputs keep the values they already have (all of them are multi-dimensional arrays). For example:

*[post.php?post=123&action=edit]*

```
<input type="text" id="field_a0b" class="text" name="fields[a][0][b]" 
value="Current value" placeholder="">
```

If I edit that post manually (as an end user would), changing `Current value` to `New value`, then hit the *Update* button, `$_POST['fields']['a'][0]['b']` will still contain `Current value` - not `New value` as I would expect.

This only happens with those input arrays. Also, if I change `name="fields[a][0][b]"` to something random, like `name="fields[a][0][bbbbbbbb]"`, and then print that thing, then I get the value I entered in the input field!

I've hacked Wordpress files to dump data from multiple places (even from *load.php*), still without success.

Not sure if this is important, but the plugin generating those HTML inputs is called ACF (Advanced Custom Fields).

Comment: Nobody?

I tried increasing `max_input_nesting_level` and `max_input_vars` in my `php.ini` (and even `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize`), but I'm still getting the same results :(

Comment: I don't think you have shown enough code context here.  Is there any javascript involved in the form posting?

Comment: No JavaScript, no browser caching. Strictly PHP, server-side weirdness.

Answer (score 0):

I have found in the past, if I'm reusing an array, that I should unset that array each time  when I'm done with it. That way you undoubtedly clear that array for reuse.